# Gmaps4rails will not display full width map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap, gmaps4rails

New to rails and doing my first trail with Gmaps4rails.  I am trying to get a map to display in a bootstrap grid column, taking up the full height and width of the column.  Any css method I use that results in width: 100%; height: 100%; results in the map not displaying.

How can I get the map displaying at full width/height?

One of my simple tests resulting in no map:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7">
  <div id="map" style='width: 100%; height: 100%;'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, thought I should mention I tried forcing html and body to 100% as suggested in another post but no luck.

Comment: Did you read the doc? https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Twitter-bootstrap-%26-Foundation

Comment: Sure did.  Added that to fix the overlay issues but it did not change the display.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting width height = 100% inside a div within the col class. Also did you add a container-fluid class with a row class inside it?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
        <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```